# Check if the value change in loop Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm making chat app by Vuejs and want to handle if messages in loop belong to new user for styling color/background-color of user's message.

```
<template v-for="msg in allMsgs">
  <li :key=msg.id>  //I want to add some class to handle if next message belong to new user.
     <span class="chatname">{{msg.user.name}}</span>
     {{msg.content}}
  </li>
</template>
```

https://prnt.sc/114ynuq

Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `computed` property to determine the position of each message according to the sequence, and then, use `class-binding` as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    allMsgs: [
      { id:1, user: { name:'B' }, content:'contentB' },
      { id:2, user: { name:'A' }, content:'contentA' },
      { id:3, user: { name:'A' }, content:'contentA' },
      { id:4, user: { name:'B' }, content:'contentB' },
      { id:5, user: { name:'B' }, content:'contentB' },
      { id:6, user: { name:'A' }, content:'contentA' },
      { id:7, user: { name:'A' }, content:'contentA' }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    messages: function() {
      let pos = 1, prev = null;
      return this.allMsgs.map((msg, index) => {
        // if msg is not the first, and it belongs to a new user, opposite pos
        if(index !== 0 && msg.user.name !== prev.user.name) pos *= -1;
        msg.position = pos;
        prev = msg;
        return msg;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chatname { font-weight:bold; }
.left { text-align:left; }
.right { text-align:right; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="(msg, index) in messages">
    <li 
      :key=msg.id 
      :class="{ 'right': msg.position === 1, 'left': msg.position === -1 }"
    >
      <span class="chatname">
        {{msg.user.name}}
      </span>
      {{msg.content}}
    </li>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: you might misunderstood my question. When a new message coming, It based on name of user to determine it's new message of new user or not. You added newUser with true and false for what purpose?

Comment: @HaiTien can you provide an example of a message object of a new user vs that of an existing one?

Comment: Sorry for my English. you can see in my screenshot above. Messages of mine is right, and other is left. Background of message of mine is grey and other is white. I want to determine: 
1. When loading existing messages, It can add left, right for each message of each users.
2. When new message of new user coming, it will determine added it in left or right, depends on previous message or that user or not.

Comment: I hope you can understand what I mean

Comment: Didn't quite understand your point. So when rendering allMsgs in the loop, you want to check if a user with its name only have one message, and if so, add the class? An example/scenario would be better here.

Comment: You can see in my new screenshot. When new message belong to new person, it appears interleaving

Comment: @HaiTien I updated the answer with a similar demo

Comment: wow. thank you so much. that is answer I need. Have a nice day